# How can I remove one drawn object from winform?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a winform and a picturebox, you can draw / place icons on the on the picturebox.

```
g2.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Warning, new Rectangle(screenPositionX, screenPositionY, _levelWidth, _levelHeight));
```

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YE9J.png)

But my problem is I want to be able to remove the warning icons with the press of a button, but I dont know how.
I already tried g2.Clear, but this removes all the icons.
I also tried just drawing over them, but this draws over everything and I can't find the correct background color.

My question is, how do I remove a single drawn object?

Comment: You maintain a list of things you want to draw, you remove the things from the list and then re render what is left

Comment: I think you have to clear, and then re-create the image. With drawing porgramms there are 2 styles: Those that just color pixels, with very limited options to undo. And those that know each and every thing to be drawn. Where you can select a specific thing to delete.

Comment: I hope that g2 is not created by CreateGraphics! - Use pbox.Paint event and its e.Graphics parm to draw from a list of things to draw as suggested and trigger pbox.Paint when that list changes by calling pbox.Invalidate() ! You will need to draw the whole list!! You should consider creating a class that hold info about what to draw and where and whether to draw it !!

Comment: Share more of your drawing code.  That one line of code you provided is hinting at a lot of potential issues.

Comment: Thank you for the advise @CaiusJard, I created a list, then stored the positions of the other icons in thelist and re rendered everything except the things I wanted to remove.

Comment: If it it only one icon you want to turn on or off you may instead nest a label with the icon as image and show and hide it..

Comment: You remove graphics by forcing a redraw (with `pictureBox.Refresh()`) not drawing the graphics.

Answer (score 1):

After you have painted something on a paper, you can't really take it back without either painting it over completely with the correct color, or discarding *(clearing)* everything and repainting only those objects that should remain. The same goes for a `PictureBox`.

If this icon is the only one that can be visible sometimes, and not visible other times, you could introduce a `bool` field in your form class. If that `bool` is `true`, you draw the icon, otherwise you don't. Then, when the user clicks the button, you can change the value of that field, and refresh the form.

Since you are showing very little code, I don't know any names of classes or methods in your solution, so consider this pseudo code!

```
// Pseudo code

class MyForm : Form
{
    // The field that decides whether to draw the icon
    private bool showWarningIcon = true;

    // The button click handler
    public void OnButtonClick()
    {
        showWarningIcon = false;
        Invalidate();
    }

    // The paint handler
    public override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // Draw other things, then:
        if (showWarningIcon)
        {
            g2.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Warning, new Rectangle(screenPositionX, screenPositionY, _levelWidth, _levelHeight));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a field that keeps track if the icons are to be drawn or not. Flip the value as a result of button presses, and when it comes time to draw (paint event) use  the value to determine what to draw.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool showIcons = true;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var wt = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Width;
        var ht = pictureBox1.ClientSize.Height;

        // draw grid
        for (int i = 0; i < wt; i+=32)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, i, 0, i, ht);
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < ht; j+=32)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 0, j, wt, j);
        }

        if (showIcons)
        {
            // draw icons
            e.Graphics.DrawIcon(SystemIcons.Warning, 5*32-1, 2*32-1);
        }
    }

    private void drawButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showIcons = true;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }

    private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        showIcons = false;
        pictureBox1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image: scr]